# sending images from mobile phone to matlab on computer

Tags: matlab

I have a project to do where I have to use a mobile phone to take a photo image and send it to remote PC which uses Matlab to compare the image with the other image clips stored. The PC should send the results back to the phone. I request anyone to tell me all the possible software tools e.g matlab_remote to program this that I may include in my proposal. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sending an image from the phone to a computer can be done using practically any web server which has an api (to check for file existance) or simply a fixed interface (where you can check for images in a specific URL) and you can upload photos to from your cellphone. Picasa, Facebook, Dropbox are just some examples. You can then get the image using that site's api.

Personally, I'd upload to Picasa (either via a web interface or using an app for doing that (most smartphones have one)), grab the rss feed and monitor it for new files. Getting the image is simply a matter of downloading a file from the url in the RSS feed.

Opening the image with matlab to do your work is a matter of running a matlab script from the command line, and you can find an example on doing it [here](http://www.mathworks.se/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/151561).

Finally, I suppose your script saves the result somehow. Assuming it's not an image and a file of some special type (so it can't be used in the above image hosting sites), you can upload it to Dropbox automatically using the explanation found [here](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=3914) (You can also use any other hosting site which supports uploading automatically). You can then download it back to your phone by some Dropbox client or using the web interface.

Final notes:

- I don't know whether any of these sites allow in their terms automatic upload/download for the reason/usage you intend to make, since I'm not a lawyer. It was just a suggestion
- Instead of trying to connect many external services, if you have your own dedicated server, just upload images/result to it using FTP or something like that and keep some file with upates of changes (which tells about images/results that were uploaded)
- This was a very unclear "request" (as you called it) without any focus on what exactly do you have available (phone OS for example would be a good start, to point you to relevant softare). More details would help giving a better answer :)